# How to specify route with parameter in paginationControl?

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I am trying to create pagination on my news feed. I have two modes in my news feed: all news feed and feed by category. Pagination for all news feed works fine, but I have problems with "feed by category" pagination.

I use paginationControl like this:

```
<?=$this->paginationControl(
    $this->news,
    'Sliding',
    'pagination_control',
    array('route' => 'news/category')
)?>
```

Route `news/category` config:

```
'category' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/:category[/page-:page]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'category'     => '[a-z]+',
            'page'     => '[1-9][0-9]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',
            'action'     => 'category',
            'page'      => 1,
        )
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
),
```

So I need to specify parameter category. I am trying this:

```
<?=$this->paginationControl(                                                                 
    $this->news,                                                                             
    'Sliding',                                                                               
    'pagination_control',                                                                    
    array('route' => 'news/category', array('category' => $this->category->getUrl()))        
)?>
```

But I am getting error "Missing parameter ...":

[image]

Looks like it is impossible to set parameter through paginationControl.

How to specify route with parameter in paginationControl **correctly**?

### Update 1

My paginationControl view looks like:

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount > 1): ?>
    <div>
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
            <!-- Previous page link -->
            <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?=$this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->previous))?>">
                        &laquo;
                    </a>
                </li>
            <? else: ?>
                <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
            <? endif; ?>

            <!-- Numbered page links -->
            <? foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
                <? if ($page != $this->current): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?=$this->url($this->route, array('page' => $page))?>">
                            <?=$page?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <? else: ?>
                    <li class="active"><span><?=$page?></span></li>
                <? endif; ?>
            <? endforeach; ?>

            <!-- Next page link -->
            <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?=$this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->next))?>">
                        &raquo;
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="small grey"><?="Страница ".$this->current." из ".$this->pageCount?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What happens when you just set up the additional params at the same level? I.e., `array('route'=>'news/category','category'=>$getUrl())`.

Comment: @raina77ow nothing hapens :( same result :(

Comment: What does your partial phtml look like?

Comment: @BramGerritsen I updated my answer and added partial html code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pass all additional parameters as an associative array at the end like @rianattow's said. In this way, all that parameters will be accessible in your `pagination_control.phtml` partial via `$this->paramname`

Example:

```
echo $this->paginationControl(                                                                 
     $this->news,                                                                             
     'Sliding',                                                                               
     'pagination_control',                                                                    
     array( 'route' => 'news/category', 'category' => 'banana')
    );
```

This detail stated in [paginator documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend-paginator-rendering):

> The fourth and final parameter is reserved for an optional associative
>   array of additional variables that you want available in your view
>   (available via $this). For instance, these values could include extra
>   URL parameters for pagination link.

I think other missing point is building the URL's using route names. Instead of passing an url to the `paginationControl()` helper as an argument, try to generate url's inside the pagination partial like this:

```
<a href="<?
    echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $page, 'category' => $this->category))
?>">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Working solution is a bit different, but you gave me an idea. I updated your answer a bit. Thank you very much. Perfect.