# ZF2 Paginator issue with child routes

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

In my application I want to add some simple pagination. Normal first level routes function without any problems but when I try to implement a paginator in a child route I get error messages. Don't know how to address my child route correctly.

I have following routes:

```
'queues' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/queues',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Mail\Controller\MailQueue',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'show' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/show/:queue_id',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'queue_id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'show',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
)
```

And here the paginationControl from the `.phtml` file to output the pagination html:

```
echo $this->paginationControl(
    // the paginator object
    $this->paginator,
    // the scrolling style
    'sliding',
    // the partial to use to render the control
    'partial/paginator.phtml',
    // the route to link to when a user clicks a control link
    array(
        'route' => 'queues/show/' . $this->queue->getId()
    )
);
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> **File:**
>     /home/norbert/dev/holding/efeedback_mail/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php:322
>
> **Message:**
>     Route with name "show" does not have child routes

When I try to give it the route without the slash:

```
array(
    'route' => 'queues/show', $this->queue->getId()
)
```

I get this segment error:

> **File:**
>     /home/norbert/dev/holding/efeedback_mail/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/Segment.php:298
>
> **Message:**
>     Missing parameter "queue_id"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify route with parameter in paginationControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146124/how-to-specify-route-with-parameter-in-paginationcontrol)

Comment: You can find your answer **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25146968/1697459)**

Comment: Oh thanks, couldnt find it myself. Will have a look